# i want to mute a particular frequency in real time audio

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, audio, frequency

i want to mute a particular frequency range in real time audio for eg: in audio signal frequency above 3 kHz should be muted for specific interval of time.

Comment: You can achieve this by running the signal through a low-pass filter, e.g. a [Butterworth filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter). This will not *mute* the signal above 3 kHz, but it will attenuate frequencies above that frequency. To apply the filter only for specific time intervals, just put the filter into the signal path for those time intervals.

Comment: thanks, but i have to stop the music at 3khz,not to filter the noise or freq.

Comment: Have you considered a notch filter at 3 kHz?

Comment: @applesoup answer is good for the question you asked. You said that you wanted to mute frequencies above 3KHz, that's what a low pass filter does. It does no only filter noise. Maybe you should clarify your question. Do you want to attenuate a narrowband around 3KHz or do you want to attenuate all frequencies above 3KHz?